Unable to inject MobX store in React test using Jest and Provider component
I am trying to write a unit test for a React component where I require a property in a MobX store to be in a non-default state.
I've been trying to modify the state and inject it into the component using <Provider> component tags.
My store looks like this:
`export class ModalControlStore {
     root: RootStore;

    constructor(root: RootStore) {
        this.root = root;
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    modalIsOpen = false;

    setModalIsOpen(isModalOpen: boolean) {
        this.modalIsOpen = modalIsOpen
    }
}`

The store is retrieved in my React component using the root store:
export function useModalControlStore() {
  const { modalControlStore  } = useRootStore();
  return modalControlStore ;
}

It is instantiated in my component like this:
const { modalIsOpen } = useModalControlStore();
Then in my test, I attempt the following:
beforeEach(() => {
    const modalControlStore = useModalControlStore();
    modalControlStore.setModalIsOpen(true);

    render(
        <Provider modalControlStore={modalControlStore}>
           <PopUpModal/>
        </Provider>
    )
});

But whenever I run my test, the value continues to be false. I followed several other paths too, but none have successfully mocked or replaced the store.

Instead of using useModalControlStore directly in test you should create and configure it manually and pass it to Provider.


describe('PopUpModal Component', () => {
  let modalControlStore;
  let rootStore;

  beforeEach(() => {

    rootStore = new RootStore();
    modalControlStore = new ModalControlStore(rootStore);

   
    modalControlStore.setModalIsOpen(true);
  });

  it('should display the modal when modalIsOpen is true', () => {
  
    const { getByText } = render(
      <Provider modalControlStore={modalControlStore}>
        <PopUpModal />
      </Provider>
    )
  // the rest of your test

  });
});


